# Unable to install QGIS, libnetcdf.so.7 not found?

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu

I recently updated my system from Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty tahr) to Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus).

While installing QGIS I get an error message:

```
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: error while loading shared libraries: libnetcdf.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I updated the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and installed the latest version

```
sudo apt-get install libnetcdf-dev
```

While checking the installation of the library I found that `libnetcdf.so.11` is installed

Checking out the available repositories for Xenial for ibnetcdf at:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libdevel/libnetcdf-dev

I found that the available library is: `libnetcdf11 (= 1:4.4.0-2)` which corresponds with the `libnetcdf.so.11` file I found.

What do I do in order to install `libnetcdf.so.7` and fulfil the dependencies for QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

I checked out the situation and I had a conflict between two installed gdal installations.

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove gdal-bin

sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove libgdal

sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove libkml-dev


sudo find /usr/local/bin/ -name 'gdal*' -delete

sudo find /usr/local/lib/ -name 'libgdal*' -delete
```

from a post at:
http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Problems-with-installing-rgdal-on-Ubuntu-quot-checking-gdal-linking-with-libs-only-no-quot-td7590255.html

then I ran a fresh gdal installation:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

Seems to work just right

Comment: For completeness, can you add where you got the wrong GDAL version from?